# Debian \ Android: Трансляция веб камеры

Tags: android, linux, debian

Здравствуйте, есть мини компьютер [cubieboard 1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubieboard) и цель: транслировать с него веб камеру (которая подключена к нему через USB).

Варианты моих решений:

1. Ставим Debian, устанавливаем ffmpeg и транслируем
2. Ставим Android, устанавливаем любое приложения для трансляции (я использовал [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam))

Я думал что первый вариант будет лучше, так как:

1. ОС без графической оболочки - меньше кушает
2. Нету всяких приложений которые бы тоже кушали ресурсы

А оказалось всё на оборот, на android трансляция работала почти идеально (задержка около 0.2с.) с хорошим разрешением.

А на Debian при разрешении 320X240 были ужасные падения FPS + задержка около 2с и ЦП загружен на 100%. А при разрешении 640X480 она вообще не работала.

Возможно чего-то я недопонимаю, но как так возможно?

Comment: Какой Debian Вы использовали?

Comment: @alexis031182 ,вот информация о ОС:   
Linux Cubian 3.4.79-sun4i #28 PREEMPT Fri Oct 10 03:17:31 CST 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux | 
No LSB modules are available. | 
Distributor ID: Debian | 
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie) | 
Release: 8.0 | 
Codename: jessie

Comment: Пробовали ли устанавливать Debian как рассказано по ссылке ниже или только Cubian?
https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Allwinner

Comment: Только Cubian, так как он специально переделан для cubieboard

Comment: Если у Вас есть уверенность в том, что система настроена как положено и работает корректно, то следующим этапом проверки должен быть, очевидно, ffmpeg. Попробуйте транслировать видео, например, не с камеры, а с какого-нибудь ролика (файла). Посмотрите, какой кодек используется Webcam, попробуйте задействовать его с ffmpeg или найти аналогичный. Вполне вероятна ситуация, что кодек, которым ffmpeg пытается кодировать видео, и "съедает" все имеющиеся ресурсы.

Comment: Webcam использует mpjpeg, при использовании его в ffmpeg, становится только хуже.
Ffmpeg лучше всего работает в mpeg.

Comment: Какая используется видеокамера? Вам трансляция со звуком нужна или mjpeg подойдет? Есть подозрение на драйверы видеокамеры

Comment: dns 1302w, без звука ,mjpeg пойдёт, коментарии к нижнему ответу почитайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аппаратный кодек - ответ на ваш вопрос. Возьмите камеру с аппаратным mjpeg и mjpeg-streamer. Роутер с 200МГц процессором вещал камеру Логитеч и был загружен при этом на 7-10%. В тоже время в ARM проццесорах есть свой кодек, которым пользуется Андроид.

Дебиан не может задействовать эти возможности по нескольким причинам: лицензионная чистота, отсутствие программиста который напишет этот модуль и упакует для Убунты (потому в репозитории Дебиана врятли возьмут).

Answer (score 12):

Задержки, они же лаги, могут происходить по многим причинам. В Вашем случае это

- проблеме с перекодированием. Устройство слабенькое, в риалтайме сложно управится.
- ffmpeg может немножко кешировать (ну как минимум на один кадр будет отставать - картинку нужно в буфер поместить, потом отправить)
- собственно сама сеть. Тут без коментариев.
- проигрыватель. Плееры также любят кешировать, потому что данные в сети не идут часто равномерным потоком и небольшая пауза вносит задержку. Потом либо нужно ускорять воспроизведение, либо придерживать задержку (которая будет накапливаться). Небольшой буфер решает проблему.

Теперь перейдем к командам.

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 25 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -fflags nobuffer -c:v copy -f sdl -
```

Тут нужно немножко уточнить. `-f v4l2 -r 25 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0` - тут все просто, выбрали формат, источник и кол-во кадров в секунду. Это выбирается по личным предпочтениям и возможностям камеры.

`-fflags nobuffer` - говорит ffmpeg не буферизировать. Может помочь немножко убрать задержку.

`-c:v copy` - это важная строка. Она говорит "не пытайся перекодировать видео. Просто копируй.

`-f sdl -` - это не будет работать, если нет gui. Эта опция говорит "выводи на экран". Она хороша для тестов, но не для реальной работы. 
Так как хочется минимум задержек, можно попробовать использовать udp (тогда нужна где то такая конструкция `-f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:8080`) или другие удобные протоколы.

Comment: Я правильно понял что эту команду(ffmpeg -f v4l2...) я должен использовать в настройках (etc/ffserver.conf) для запуска, а не на прямую в консоль?

Comment: если я все правильно понимаю, то вначале запускается ffserver, а потом ffmpeg, просто ему указывают на ранее запущенный ffserver. Чуточку больше [деталей](http://habrahabr.ru/post/78677/).

Comment: Смотри получается так:
Я запускаю ffserver(в котором настроен stream), далее запускаю ffmpeg с указанием ,куда передавать данные ,а ffserver уже перекодирует и создаёт поток, возможно в нём нужно настраивать что-то?
Вот что получается:  
http://joxi.ru/QY2LWBqTEPyym6.jpg

Comment: как минимум 1 секунду можно убрать сразу - в vlc, который используется, на вкладке network (которое в open media) нужно нажать "show more options" и там выбрать нулевой размер буфера (по умолчанию он одна секунда).
С перекодированием в ffserver ситуация хуже - https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-March/014172.html - его там похоже нет и не будет.

Comment: В VLC я убираю буферезацию, и что же делать?
Он даже нормально при такой задержки не работает, когда камера шевелится ,не завиксирована в одно место, то очень много кадров пропускаются, можно сказать в момент перемещения камеры я не чего не вижу, только после остановки кадрый приходят.

Comment: в терминале на фоне я вижу кучу слов "underflow" - это очень похоже на вывод ffmpeg и значит, что источник "недоливает".  К примеру, камера должна давать 30 кадров в секунду, а по факту выдает пять, потому что скорость передачи от камеры маленькая. И в этом случае кадры будут "выпадать". Попробуйте уменьшить кол-во кадров/разрешение камеры или выбрать формат видео от камеры другой до полного исчезновения указанной ошибки.

А может просто устройство слабенькое и физически не справляется.

Comment: Вот что полностью пишется в терминале:
С лево - ffmpeg  ,с право ffserver
http://joxi.ru/qVrwwNQC4eYarX.jpg

На счёт устройство не справляется, я бы тоже так подумал, но ведь на Android всё прекрасно работает, вот в чём вопрос..

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте mjeg_streamer вместо ffmpeg. На нем проще подобрать подходящий fps и разрешение экрана.
Ну и камера *dns 1302w* - не самый лучший выбор для таких задач. Вполне возможно, что в android где-то чтение с дешевых китайских видеокамер реализовано лучше Не помешало бы сравнить версии ядер.